# Is a current limiting resistor needed for dual opamp supply pins?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, resistors

Consider the TL072 dual op amp that is supplied with +/- 12V. The datasheet says that the supply current for (each) amplifier is typically 1.4 mA, with maximum of 2.5 mA. If both amplifiers are operating, should the current be limited to 2.5 mA on each supply pin? So I would use ~4.8 ohm resistors in series with the supply pins to limit the current to a maximum of 2.5 mA. Is this the correct interpretation of the datasheet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The supply current stated is the maximum current the op amp will draw with no load.  There is no need to current limit the input as in e.g. a LED, just make sure that whatever you're driving keeps output current and maximum supply current within datasheet values.  More detailed discussion [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa011b/sloa011b.pdf?ts=1651172043825).

Comment: Putting a resistor in series with the supply pins to ensure current stays below max ratings is detrimental or just being extra-cautious?

Comment: In your case, detrimental.  The op amp will only draw as much current as it needs.  Adding resistors will cause the voltage at the input of the op amp to fluctuate when the output current changes which is generally a bad thing.  Also, your calculated resistor is off by a factor of 1000.  There is a case for adding low value resistors in the supply lines along with C and/or L to isolate op amps from each other, but that's a different application.  See: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/275755/rc-low-pass-filters-for-op-amp-power-in-pins

Answer (score 3):

Besides the fact that you don't need current limiting for an opamp, adding a resistor wouldn't really work very well.

The value you came up with, 4.8 Ω, would allow a maximum of 2.5 A of current at 12 V, not 2.5 mA. To limit the current to 2.5 mA you would need 4800 Ω, and at that current all of the voltage would be dropped across the resistor, this would only happen if the opamp was short circuited. If you went somewhere in the middle, say 2400 Ω, you would drop half the supply voltage at 2.5 mA and your opamp would have 6 V supplies.

So the lower the resistance, the higher the available current, the higher the resistance the higher the voltage drop, it's a Catch-22. Resistors do not make good current limiters for varying loads, that's why fuses exist. They can be used for things like LEDs where the load is relatively constant though.